# How to set the RichTextBox curser to the end?

Tags: c#

I am using `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` and doing something like

```
RichTextBox1.Text = "Hello World";
```

But after this statement the cursor position of in the RichTextBox remains in the beginning. Is there any way to set it to the end?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.Text.Length - 1, 0);
```

**Edit:** If you have a lot of text in the textbox and which it to scroll the caret into view too, add this line:

```
RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s.aspx) for more.

Comment: It's an old toppic but it helpen me out, almost. The `.Length()` in:
`RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.Text.Length() - 1, 0);` should just be `.length` as it is a property and not a method

Comment: I removed the brackets after Length.

Comment: I ran into two issues with this, both solved by taking out the `- 1`.  It errors if there is no text, and it positions the cursor one character before the end.  So would taking out the `- 1` work better, or am I missing something?